# Ubuntu Server login not recognizing the keyboard after entering username

Tags: login

I'm having similar issues with logging into ubuntu server. chief problem is that once I enter my user name & hit enter, I can't enter anything ffor my password - it won't accept any keystrokes until I press Ctrl+any key. Once I've pressed Ctrl+ any key, I'm able to type again, but have never been able to enter any more than 3 characters before the 60 sec time limit. This problem is present on fresh installs of both 10.04 & 9.10. Part of the problem is lkely to be my antique pc which is an old Emachines Trigems I850 based mbd and an equally ancient Nvidia 4x AGP video card. Initially I was going to install Ubuntu 10.10, but with ORCA running with both screen reader and full screen magnification crashed the system & smoked a stick of Rambus memory. Is there any fix to this problem?

Jeff

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting problem. If you have time add and configure serial console to observe all diagnostic data. Also send `dmesg` output to ubuntu mailling list, or other bug tool. There should be someone who can help you...